# ¿Puedo crear un usuario a la medida en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

`Wordpress` permite que los visitantes se registren en tu sitio web, pero ellos te ofrecen unos usuarios por defecto con acceso a ciertas cosas, yo como administrador de mi sitio ¿puedo crear un usuario a la medida? Que yo mismo sea quien decida a que tiene acceso y a que no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que puedes hacerlo, para manejar roles y capacidades en wordpress, puedes probar usando las siguientes funciones:

- `add_role():` Permite agregar un rol customizado.
- `remove_role():`   Elimina un rol.
- `get_role ():` Obtiene información acerca del rol y las capacidades
  asociadas al mismo.

Por ejemplo para crear un nuevo rol podrías hacer algo así:

```
$result = add_role( 'client', __('Client' ),
array(
'read' => true, // true activa la capacidad, false la desactiva.
'edit_posts' => true, // Permite al usuario editar sus propios posts
'edit_pages' => true, // Permite al usuario editar páginas
'edit_others_posts' => true, // Permite al usuario editar otros post no solos los suyos.
'create_posts' => true, // Permite al usuario crear posts
'manage_categories' => true, // Permite al usuario manejar categorias 
'edit_themes' => false, // El usuario no puede editar el tema
'install_plugins' => false, // El usuario no puede instalar nuevos pluggins
'update_plugin' => false, // El usuario no puede actualizar plugins
'update_core' => false // El usuario no puede realizar updates del core

)

);
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Así lo estaba haciendo y me funciono a la perfección hasta que me encontre con el Plugin *User Role Editor*

Comment: También es una alternativa, en base a tu pregunta pensé que estabas buscando la manera de hacerlo a través de las funciones que provee wordpress, me alegro que hayas resuelto tus dudas.